# Identify elements involved in a log product

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

Since we know that $\log_2 ab = \log_2 a + \log_2 b$, is there a way to figure out numerical values of $a$ and $b$ (or even $\log_2 a$ and $\log_2 b$) if we are just given the value of $\log_2 ab$?

Comment: Do you mean $$\log_{ab}{2}=\log_{a}{2}+\log_{b}{2}$$?

Comment: Nope. I meant `log(a*b, 2) = log(a, 2) + log(b, 2)` (the product rule of logarithms) where a, b are both Q+.

Comment: My intent is to identify `a` and `b` involved if just `log(a*b, base2)` is given.

Comment: Ok $2$ should be the base:

Comment: $$\log_{2}{ab}=\log_{2}{a}+\log_{2}{b}$$

Comment: yes .. 2 is the base.

Comment: If $2c$ and $d/2$ were and answer, would $c$ and $d$ also be an answer?

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Do you realize there are multiple choices for $a,b$ given just $\log_2{ab}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-Hand side can be written as

$$\frac{\ln(a)+\ln(b)}{\ln(2)}$$
and $b$ is given by,
$$b=e^{p\ln(2)-\ln(a)}$$ and this is $$b=\frac{2^p}{a}$$ where $$p=\log_{2}{ab}$$

Comment: Thoughtful and interesting. What is `p` though?

Comment: $$p=\log_{2}{ab}$$ given as you said.

Comment: That's wonderful. Thank you. So, in situations when both `a` and `b` are unknown and only `p` is known, there is no way to recover `a` and `b`?

Comment: I think so,there is no other way.

Comment: You can also consider a numerical example for this case

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Not uniquely. We have
$$ \log_2(ab) = C \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad ab = 2^C, $$
and the latter is solved by infinitely many pairs $(a,b)$.

However, if you also know $a$ then you can find $b$ and vice versa.

Comment: If we know `a`, then `b` is `2^C/a` and can be uniquely recovered, right?

Comment: Exactly! Assuming, of course, that both of your numbers are positive in the first place.